# How to combine positional argument with an optional one?

Tags: python, argparse

Let`s suppose I have some usage for myprog:

```
myprog.py [-h] [-d DEPTH] [-v] [--version] URL [URL ...]
```

And now I want to allow `-d DEPTH` option only when **single** positional argument `URL` is specified. For example, this is a correct cmd:

```
my_prog.py http://stackoverflow.com -d 5
my_prog.py http://stackoverflow.com http://google.com
```

but this one should not be allowed (the number of urls more then one):

```
my_prog.py http://stackoverflow.com http://google.com -d 5
```

So, now I`m trying to check this case like as follows:

```
parser = get_parser()
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

if args['depth'] > 1:
        if len(args['url']) != 1:
            parser.error('DEPTH parameter is allowed with single URL')
            return
```

I think that this solution is not rather good.

Comment: I think this solution is great. Why don't you? Argparser isn't supposed to have a built in method for every possible imaginable case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you'd also like to disallow

```
my_prog.py -d 5 http://stackoverflow.com http://google.com
```

that is, when the `-d` is specified before the URL argument.  Since the arguments can be given in either order, it makes most sense to test them after parsing is done - as you are doing.

It is possible to construct custom Action classes that test things like this, but the logic becomes more convoluted.  The 'url' action would have to test for previous '-d' settings, and the '-d' would have to test the 'url' attribute, etc.